# Use Powershell to access API behind Data-Gateway

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerapps, data-gateway, powerbi-datagateway

I have been trying to make a REST request from within a Powershell script to a service behind a Data-Gateway (deployed on premise).
I couldn't find any information about any Powershell modules that would allow us to contact Data-Gateway services via REST.

Is there any way to consume the services behind the Data-Gateway using REST requests ? (without using the Power Bi or Power Apps API).

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For REST API's you want [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-7.2) .

Comment: Well, how would I contact the Data-Gateway using the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet ?
When used within Power Apps the Data-Gateway is directly detected and proposed as a Data Souce. Is there anyway to contact it with a POST REST request ? (Thanks for the reply)

Comment: Check out <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways> and <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/>