# Can Microsoft On-Premises Data Gateways be accessed from a non-Power client

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerapps

On-premises data gateways allow "clean" access to SQL and HTTP resources behind NAT and firewalls.  They work very reliably and support small and very large deployments.  Is there a supported way to call upon a SQL or HTTP resource accessible to a gateway from an arbitrary C# client?

Terrible ascii-art example of what is intended:

```
[ MyAwesomeApp.exe running in Azure ]
               |
               V
 [ On-premises data gateway API ]
               |
           Internet
               |
               V
  [ On-premises data gateway ]
               |
               V
    [ On-prem SQL Server ]
```

Related: [Use Powershell to access API behind Data-Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177885/use-powershell-to-access-api-behind-data-gateway)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-what-is-it

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, thanks.  I can't accept since duplicate, but that looks like a direct solution.